# if is NOT custom post type OR is NOT page combination

Tags: conditional-tags

I'm running a site with a LOT of plugins.  I'm trying to deregister some scripts and css files on posts/ CPTs/ pages so they don't load where they aren't necessary.  Basically, I'm deregistering when things are NOT true.  This code works for pages `!is_page()` only, but I can't seem to add custom post types `!is_singular()`.  Here's the code:

```
if ( !is_page(array('my-resumes','resume-listings', 'submit-job', 'submit-resume', 'job-alerts', 'job-listings', 'my-jobs', 'my-bookmarks' ) ) || !is_singular( array( 'job_listing', 'job'  )) ) {
// disappear some stuff
```

Comment: What if you change `||` to `&&` ?

Comment: That... worked!!?  I figured we wanted an OR operator here.  Looks like I get to do some more research on PHP logic!  Would you like to add an answer to the question so I can give you some fake internet points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `&&` instead of `||`.

Like:

```
if ( !is_page(array('my-resumes','resume-listings', 'submit-job', 'submit-resume', 'job-alerts', 'job-listings', 'my-jobs', 'my-bookmarks' ) ) 
&& !is_singular( array( 'job_listing', 'job'  )) ) {
// disappear some stuff
```

Comment: I think your answer would benefit from an explanation WHY this works.